# How to create a custom content control linked to its copies with VBA?

Tags: xml, vba, ms-word, contentcontrol

I would like to create a set of customized content controls in Word to be able to easily copy-paste them manually later on inside the same document. The trick is to get the same value in every copy by editing just one of them.

The code below imports custom xml nodes, inserts one control and maps it to corresponding node. I'm clueless why this copied control is not linked with it's original one. The value does not change after editing.

This is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Add_Content_Controls()

    On Error GoTo Err_NoXMLPart
    Dim oCustomPart As Office.CustomXMLPart: Set oCustomPart = ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts(4)

Err_ReEntry:
    Dim oCC As Word.ContentControl: Set oCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add
    With oCC
        .Type = wdContentControlRichText
        .Title = "Main_Doc_Number"
        .Tag = "Main"
        .SetPlaceholderText , , "Placeholder"
        .LockContentControl = True
        .Color = wdColorDarkRed
        .XMLMapping.SetMapping "/Document/Main/Main_Doc_Number[1]"
    End With
    Exit Sub

Err_NoXMLPart:
    ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts.Add:  ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts(ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts.Count).Load ("D:\Downloads\DocumentXMLPart.txt")
    Resume Err_ReEntry
    
End Sub
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<Document xmlns="Document">

    <Main>
        <Main_Doc_Number></Main_Doc_Number>
        <Main_Doc_Title></Main_Doc_Title>
    </Main>

    <Seconday>
        <Sec_Doc_Number></Sec_Doc_Number>
        <Sec_Doc_Title></Sec_Doc_Title>
    </Seconday>

</Document>
```

Comment: You have to either remove the `xmlns` from the `Document`-tag - or you have to include the namespace in the xpath when mapping

Comment: @Ike Certainly works now when the `xmlns` tag is removed. I'm curious... do you know how to include it in xpath?

Comment: Here is Greg Maxey's page about repeating information in Word. Please see section 7 about Content Controls. https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/repeating_data.html

Comment: @JohnKorchok Greg's script is basically what I used to create mine. Though his version still doesn't include the namespace reference in xpath.

Comment: To reference a namespace you need the prefix that Word assigns (dynamically) to the URI. To get that, in your example, you could use oCustomPart.NameSpaceManager.LookupPrefix("Document") . (In fact Word will probably return "ns0" (and a lot of people *assume* that, but strictly speaking you shouldn't assume). Then prefix each step in your xpath with that prefix, e.g. /ns0:Document/ns0:Main/ns0:Main_Doc_Number[1] . You may be able to get away with less than that but you'll need a good XPath tutorial to decide what's essential and what is not,